# How to mock Iterable Array using Mockito Iterable<int[]>

Tags: java, mockito

**Code**:

```
for (Int[] 
dArray:apData.createvaluetraversalbasis(nbvautoxpathconstant.DRIVER))
```

Here Return type of this method `createvaluetraversalbasis` is Iterable `int[]`. I tried to mock this as below.

**Junits:**

```
Iterable int[]=new Iterable int[];

ApDatacollection apData=Mockito.mock(ApDatacollection.class);
```

`Mockito.when(apData.createvaluetraversalbasis(nbvautoxpathconstants.DRIVER)).thenReturn(IdArray);`

**Result:** I am getting compile error for this. Can someone please help me how to mock iterable array.

Comment: Can you post the error you are receiving?

Comment: Please format your code as code. Indent by 4 spaces for a block of code, wrap in backticks (`\`\``) for inline.

Comment: Using the AP DataCollection, which is what I assume that's what this is AgencyPort, you are better using powermockito and forcing the return. Mocking java classes is awful, mocking AgencyPort is slightly less.

Comment: Without more context on `what the exception is?`, `what is the piece of code that you are trying to test?` and what's `what's the structure of class/method that you are trying to mock?` it would be hard to help you. I would not even go ahead to suggest a framework without answer to these questions.

Comment: public boolean evaluate(ResultNode aggregateResult) implements Icustomvalidation { for (Int[] idArray:apData.createvaluetraversalbasis(nbvautoxpathconstant.DRIVER)) { String segmentCd=apData.getFieldValue(NbvAutoxpathConstants.SEG_MENTATION_CODE) if("B","C".equalsIgnoreCase(segmentCd)) { return true; } } return false; } I am testing this piece of code. I am getting null pointer Exception,Which means i didn't mock this properly so i am getting null pointer exception. Can some once help me how to mock this.

Comment: Why would you have to create a mock iterable. Just create a plain old list: Arrays.asList(new int[] {1, 2}, new int[] {3, 4}). Also, please post correctly formatted, valid code. There is no Int in Java. This is working fine.